# Female background? vocalists singing 'take a chance take a chance' NOT ABBA

Tags: band

It could be from the seventies or eighties. Sounds like R&B, also background voices similar to Love and Kisses 'Thank God It's Friday'

Comment: Hi Eric Samera. Song identification questions are not a topic addressed on this site. The Stack Exchange Music Fans site does take this kind of question; just know, they require more detailed information than is currently included in your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because song identification questions are off-topic here.